# Debug multiple copies of a program from one Visual Studio instance

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I have a pre-alpha GUI program that I'm [dogfooding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eat_one%27s_own_dog_food) and want to run under the debugger (for when things go wrong `;)`, but I don't want to have to launch a new copy of Visual Studio for each instance of the application. Can this be done?

I don't expect to actually be debugging more than one instance at a time, but I still want the debugger in the look for all of them. Also, I'm starting the application a few dozen time a day, so it would have to be easy to do.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I still want the debugger in the look"*?

Answer (score 21):

You can start an instance of the same, or different projects multiple times in one instance of Visual Studio. Here is how: Right click on any project in Solution Explorer, go to the *Debug* context menu item, and click *Start new instance*.

You can view and manipulate all your running processes from the *Processes* window (menu *Debug* → *Windows* → *Processes*). The menu item (and the *Processes* window) is only available when the application is running (under Visual Studio).

Comment: See [Debug Multiple Processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919165.aspx). In "Switch between processes" it says "only one process is active in the debugger at any given time".

Answer (score 4):

This can be done.

If you have the *Professional* version of Visual Studio, you can use it to attach to each instance of the application that you have open.

First, compile the application with debug information so that it can actually be debugged.

Then launch your application. Open as many instances as you need.

In Visual Studio, click menu *Debug* → *Attach to Process...*. Select the process(es) you want to debug. You can select more than one from the list by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + clicking or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + clicking them.

I've just tested this to make sure. One instance of Visual Studio (at least Visual Studio 2008) can debug multiple instances of the same application.

If you don't have the *Professional* version I don't think this can be done. I'm absolutely sure the *Express* version can **not** attach to processes. I'm not sure about what "paid" editions can attach to processes though it is possible to do.

Comment: You can only attach to one instance, and if visual studio is already watching the process, you can't attach again.

Comment: I just tried this myself and it works. Obviously you can't attach to the SAME process more than once, but if you open multiple instances you can attach to each separate process. This works.

Comment: Yuck, Not near as nice a "just hit F5" but +1 anyway.

Comment: It might not be pretty, but this type of thing is done so rarely that I guess MS didn't feel it needed an easy solution.