# Can I run two instances of a XAML file in a Visual Studio project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Hi There: Noob question

I am working on learning C# Asyn server and client sockets.My server accepts multiple clients together and I want to run 2+ clients simulatenously to test it

In Eclipse when working on a similar Java application, I could simply (F9)run my server.java and then run client.java TWICE by clicking run.

How can I achieve something similar in Visual Studio, do I have to run multiple instances of Visual studio, or is there a way to do it as it is done in eclipse?
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debug multiple copies of a program from one VS instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447840/debug-multiple-copies-of-a-program-from-one-vs-instance)

Comment: Yes, I couldnt thinkg of the right "words" when searching, should I delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the client project, Debug/Run->Start new instance.